# Missing files libresolv.9.dylib and libxml2.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode7, resolve, xml-libxml

I have an old Xcode project for iOS where I used libxml2.dylib and libresolv.9.dylib. After installing XCode7.

I can't find the files and I don't know where to search. Can someone help me?

Comment: This might help, but seriously have a search on Google: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/8609#8609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new Xcode and new iOS the links with the libresolv.9.dylib and libxml2.dylib must be updated removing the reference from Target->Building Phases and adding the new files: the files are now in a different folder:

> /Users/yyyyyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/9.0
>   (xxxxxx)/Symbols/usr/lib

where yyyyyy is the user name and xxxxxx the iOS bulild.

Comment: Can't find developer folder

Answer (score 17):

SleepyViking's answer in [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/4572#8609) provides a shortcut to find missing .dylib files.

> 1. Go to Build Phases > Link Binary with Librairies > + > Add other
> 2. Once in the file selection window do "CMD"+Shift+G (Go to folder) and type /usr/lib/
> 3. From /usr/lib you can add : libz.dylib and more...
> 4. Compile and have fun

Comment: Don't forget to also add `/usr/include/libxml2` to your Header Search Paths in Build Settings.