# ld: library not found for -lnfshared in iOS 9.0

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, xcode7, cocos2d-x-2.x

I opened a project with new Xcode (Version 7.0) and there was some errors connected with CoreText.framework and lnfshared.dylib. All libraries with  *.dylib I've changed to  *.tbd. Now there is only one error in compilation:

```
ld: library not found for -lnfshared
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Has anybody encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in build setting. Deployment target was from 6.0. I've change it to 7.0 and the error disappeared

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved searching the files in a different path.
Look a this link
[Missing files libresolv.9.dylib and libxml2.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32550557/missing-files-libresolv-9-dylib-and-libxml2-dylib/32799420#32799420)

Comment: In "/Users/yyyyyy/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/" I do not have 9.x, however already have started all simulators on ios 9 with other projects.

Comment: You should find 9.x or 8.x based on the different iOS. Tell me if you solve the problem.

Comment: nope(
Found it in 8.x folder. added library from there. but it does not help.

Comment: In my case I have removed the old reference from the project end added the new and all was fine. probably for you there is something else.

Comment: don't even know what to clean else... rebuilded, close xcode, remove old libraries... nothing. The same problem